# How do we select an Operation in JMX Policy through WLST?

Tags: weblogic, jmx, wlst

In the below example , after the ls() operation we got the list of attributes and operations.We can set the value of attributes by using "set" command.But how do we select the operations(unset,addPolicy) or how do set the value of operations?

```
wls:/offline> connect("weblogic","weblogic1", "t3://localhost:7001")  
wls:/atgdomain/serverConfig>    
cd("Servers/CRMDemo_server1/Log/CRMDemo_server1")
wls:/atgdomain/serverConfig/Servers/CRMDemo_server1/Log/CRMDemo_server1>          
ls()
dr--   DomainLogBroadcastFilter
dr--   LogFileFilter
-r--   FileMinSize                                  5000
-r--   FileName                                     logs/CRMDemo_server1.log
 .
 .
 .
-r-x   addPolicy                                    Void : String(policy)
-r-x   unSet                                        Void : String(propertyName)
```

For ex:
In order to modify "FileMinSize" log attribute we make use of set() command as follows

```
set("FileMinSize", 400)
```

How do we do it for operations(unSet,addPolicy) in our case?

Answer (score 0):

just call the method on the cmo object like this : cmo.addPolicy(...)

Comment: Suppose if i have a operations as "advance" of type Void : String(cursor) , Could you tell/explain how it can be called? Thanks